# How to save local json file to zip file in Swift apple watch

Tags: ios, json, swift, apple-watch, zip

I am doing apple watch app using Swift. I am getting some data using user workout from Healthkit.

I am saving data to local json file, But, I have to store that json file to zip file locally.

```
guard let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
                let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("sample.json")
                do {
                       let jsonFile = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: localDictionary, options: [])
                       try jsonFile.write(to: fileUrl, options: [])
                   } catch {
                       print(error)
                   }
```

How to store this json file to zip file locally.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive

Comment: Is it possible without using third party library?

Comment: I have upvoted first answer. Please check it @EmreSURK

Comment: Actually, i have tried another way to fix my issue, and it's got fixed that time. So, that is why I did not tried other's solutions. Hope you got my point @EmreSURK

Comment: Does Apple's new Compression framework help with this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression